# React PropTypes: how to specify PropType for children of component to accept two types of subcomponents?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, react-proptypes

I'm currently building a large component that should only take two components as children (in this case, a TopBar and a NavBar). So far, I've tried specifying the propType for the children as this:

```
AppHeader.propTypes = {
  /**
   * AppHeader should ONLY accept TopBar and NavBar components as children.
   */
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf([
    PropTypes.instanceOf(TopBar),
    PropTypes.instanceOf(NavBar),
  ]),
};
```

However, the PropTypes aren't working for me. I'm facing this problem with a similar component that can take a random  number of two types of subcomponents.

How should I go about creating this PropTypes for the children where you specify the type of components that it can take. (This is not an enum since an enum is 'either or'/ oneOf).

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this but it seems that `PropTypes.arrayOf` doesn't accept an `Array`. Instead try providing the `PropTypes.oneOfType` object. Then pass your array into that.

```
AppHeader.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.oneOfType([
      PropTypes.instanceOf(TopBar),
      PropTypes.instanceOf(NavBar),
    ])
  ),
};
```

references:
https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes
https://blog.logrocket.com/validating-react-component-props-with-prop-types-ef14b29963fc/